How to terminate EC2 instance if `user-data` script exits with not-zero status code?
So EC2 was created but user-data failed, eg. syntax error, some command failed etc.
How to terminate such instance automatically if a user-data run was not successful?

If I were to come up with a solution to automatically terminate an EC2 instance if its user-data script fails, I’ll add error handling in the user-data script to terminate the instance using AWS CLI if any command fails. Something like this :
#!/bin/bash
set -e  # to stop script execution on any error

# Example command that might fail
let’s-assume-your-command-is-here || { 
    echo "Command failed"; 
    aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids $(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --region $(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/region); 
    exit 1; 
}

If you want to explore this approach, make sure to ensure the EC2 instance has an IAM role with permissions to terminate itself. It’ll need a policy like this:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "Resource": "*" # you can make this more specific
        }
    ]
}

I’ll also suggest you test by simulating failures to ensure it terminates as expected.

Make sure AWS CLI is installed in the instance.
Consider implementing logging (to say S3 or CloudWatch) before termination for debugging purposes.

This is how I’ll approach this scenario. Hope it helps.

You got me the idea.
